# Accepting a list, splitting the elements in sublists and printing together

Tags: python-3.x

Currently learning Python through freecodecamp.org and other resources. I have difficulty grasping the concept of splitting a list in sublists and iterating over them. I have an assignment of different exercises that need to be printed in order.

The thing is, I have it working for when the input is only 1 exercise. I just can't seem to make it work by giving it a list. What am I missing?

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, answer=False):
    for som in problems:
        
        sumlist = list(som.split())
        
        getal_a=(sumlist[0])
        operatie= sumlist[1]
        getal_b=(sumlist[2])
        
        #reformat = "{:>9}\n{:>3}   {:>2}\n    -----".format(getal_a, operatie, getal_b)
        getal_1=int(getal_a)
        getal_2=int(getal_b)
        if answer == False:
                antwoord=''

        if answer==True:
            if operatie.strip() == '+':
                antwoord=getal_1 + getal_2
            elif operatie.strip() == '-':
                antwoord=getal_1-getal_2
            elif operatie.strip() == '*' or operatie.strip() == 'x':
                antwoord=getal_1*getal_2
            elif operatie.strip() == ':':
                antwoord=getal_1/getal_2
            
        reformat = "{:>9}\n{:>3}   {:>2}\n    -----\n {:>8}".format(getal_1, operatie, getal_2, antwoord)
        
       
        return reformat
```

For calling the function: I use True when I also want the answer and False for when it has to be hidden.

```
practise=["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]
print(arithmetic_arranger(practise, True))
```

My current and *preferred* result is like this, but it only seems to get the first element in the list. So to me it feels like I am very close, but can't seem to able to fix it without ruining my current results.

```
       32
  +   698
    -----
      730
```

expected:

```
       32      3801
  +   698     -   2
    -----     -----     etc
      730      3799
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions take input and return output, the moment they return output they're job is done, they exit, and the interpreter proceeds with the rest of the program.

your function returns the reformat for the first member of the list and exits because your return statement is inside the loop

what you might consider is through each iteration of the loop you print the reformat, or if you want to store it you append the reformat to a list, and after you're done with the list, you return it outside of the loop.

and then you can loop through the returned list to print each member

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, answer=False):

reformat_list = [] #/////////////////////////////////////////////////
for som in problems:

    sumlist = list(som.split())

    getal_a=(sumlist[0])
    operatie= sumlist[1]
    getal_b=(sumlist[2])

    #reformat = "{:>9}\n{:>3}   {:>2}\n    -----".format(getal_a, operatie, getal_b)
    getal_1=int(getal_a)
    getal_2=int(getal_b)
    if answer == False:
            antwoord=''

    if answer==True:
        if operatie.strip() == '+':
            antwoord=getal_1 + getal_2
        elif operatie.strip() == '-':
            antwoord=getal_1-getal_2
        elif operatie.strip() == '*' or operatie.strip() == 'x':
            antwoord=getal_1*getal_2
        elif operatie.strip() == ':':
            antwoord=getal_1/getal_2

    reformat = "{:>9}\n{:>3}   {:>2}\n    -----\n {:>8}".format(getal_1, operatie, getal_2, antwoord)
    reformat_list.append(reformat) #///////////////////////////////


return reformat_list #///////////////////////////////// changed indentation
```

and then calling the function:

```
practise=["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]
list_of_reformated_arithmetic= arithmetic_arranger(practise, True)

for i in range(len(list_of_reformated_arithmetic)):
print(something[i], end = "\n\n")
```

the result of this would be:

```
    32
+   698
  -----
    730


   3801
-    2
  -----
   3799


     45
+   43
  -----
     88


    123
+   49
  -----
    172
```

printing them side by side is something more challenging and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This solution is almost perfect! The thing is the assignment states that it returns the arranged problems meaning that your call of the function has to be integrated within. Is that even possible? I've used your feedback and tips combined with the help of comments underneath to make my code better. So close though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with the new [f-stings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Makes you line easier to understand.

```
reformat = "{:>9}\n{:>3}   {:>2}\n    -----\n {:>8}".format(getal_1, operatie, getal_2, antwoord)
```

will become

```
reformat = f"{getal_1:>9}\n{operatie:>3}   {getal_2:>2}\n    -----\n {antwoord:>8}"
```

As you can see, you're outputting one addition. You would need to put it all in a huge reformat string which becomes confusing. Why not writing it into a csv file or parse it into a html?

Some small other hints:

```
if answer==True:
```

as your variable answer is a boolean already, it is enough to write
`if answer:` or `if not answer:` for the opposite.

No need to put your `.split()` into a `list()` as split returns a list already. And the result is striped, too. No need to `.strip()` neither.

Reconsider your code. Including the input.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I agree, it makes the code much more cleaner. I've integrated your tips in my currentcode. I've achieved the desired result by using a Print(statement) before my return. Is it possible to let the function return with a for loop print statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(a):
    results = []
    add = lambda x,y: int(x) + int(y)
    sub = lambda x,y: int(x) - int(y)
    mul = lambda x,y: int(x) * int(y)
    div = lambda x,y: int(x) / int(y)
    for i in a:
        x = i.split(" ")
        if x[1] == '+':
            v = add(x[0],x[2])
        elif x[1] == '-':
            v = sub(x[0],x[2])
        elif x[1] == '*':
            v = mul(x[0],x[2])
        elif x[1] == '/':
            v = div(x[0],x[2])
        # formating output string
        dashes = ""
        if len(x[2]) > len(x[0]):
            x[2], x[0] = (x[0], x[2])
        dif = len(x[0]) - len(x[2])
        for _ in range(dif):
            x[2] = " " + x[2]
        for _ in range(len(x[0])):
            dashes += "-"
        result = f"  {x[0]}\n{x[1]} {x[2]}\n  {dashes}\n  {v}" 
        results.append(result)
    return results

a = ["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"]
answers = test(a)
for answer in answers:
    print(f"{answer}\n")
```

Output

```
  698   
+  32   
  ---   
  730   
        

  3801  
-    2  
  ----  
  3799  
        
        
  45    
+ 43    
  --    
  88    
        
        
  123   
+  49   
  ---   
  172
```